# How can i create a patch file in mercurial that contains also the changes from contained subrepo's

Tags: mercurial

We are working with severall people on the same project and are using Mercurial as our DVCS. Our project does have severall subrepos.
We do need to send patches to each other by mail, because it is at this moment impossible to push and pull from the master repo.
The export command - if executed on the master will only create a patch for the master, and not for the subrepo's. We could manually create pathes for those, but we would like to know if there is an easier way to do this?

Comment: Yo can call me dumb, but: why you use DVCS as CVCS? If teammates can mail, they can pull from other members repo. hg serve works for everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martin suggested, i wrote my own extension. I will post the code here, in the hope someone will improve it or make it defaulf available in mercurial ...

Thanks Martin, i based it on your onsub extension, and yes i know there are a few problems with it, but for now, it serves its purpose. (problems with more than 10 subrepos and more than 1 level of nesting)

```
"""execute the Bundle command in a repository and each subrepository"""

# bundlesb.py - execute the Bundle command in a repository and each subrepository
#
# Copyright 2012 Johan G.
#
# This software may be used and distributed according to the terms of
# the GNU General Public License version 2 or any later version.

import os
import zipfile
from mercurial.i18n import _
from mercurial import extensions, subrepo, util

def bundlesb(ui, repo, *args, **opts):
    """execute the Bundle command in a repository and each subrepository

    Creates a combined bundle (with hgs extention) for the current 
    repository. 

    Because the revision numbers of the root and the subrepos will differ,
    we cannot reliably choose a revision to start from. A date to start
    from should be nice, but i have not taken the time to implement this.
    Instead i choose to take the N (default=10) last changesets into account.
    This seems to work well in our environment. Instead of providing the
    number of changesets for the operation, you can also specify -a to
    include all changesets. 

    Use --verbose/-v to print information and the subrepo
    name for each subrepo. 
    """
    ui.status("Starting operation\n")
    zipname = os.path.splitext(' '.join(args))[0]
    if (zipname==''):
       zipname = os.path.join(repo.root, os.path.split(repo.root)[1])
       #raise ValueError("FILE cannot be empty")
    zipname= zipname + '.hgs'
    allchangesets=opts.get('all')
    changesets=opts.get('changesets')
    ui.debug(_("input filename=%s ; AllChangesets=%s ; Changesets=%s \n") % (zipname, allchangesets, changesets))
    files=[]

    #work on the root repository
    runcmd(ui, repo.root, files, "0Root", repo['.'].rev(), ".", changesets, allchangesets)

    #do the same for each subrepository
    foreach(ui, repo, files, changesets, allchangesets)

    # open the zip file for writing, and write stuff to it
    ui.status("creating file: " + zipname + "\n\n")

    file = zipfile.ZipFile(zipname, "w" )
    for name in files:
        file.write(name, os.path.basename(name), zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    file.close()

    # open the file again, to see what's in it

    file = zipfile.ZipFile(zipname, "r")
    for info in file.infolist():
        ui.debug(info.filename + " " + str(info.date_time) + " " + str(info.file_size) + " " + str(info.compress_size) +"\n")
        #delete all the compressed .hg files
    os.remove(os.path.join(repo.root, info.filename)) 

    ui.status("\nOperation complete\n")


def foreach(ui, repo, files, changesets, allchangesets):
    ctx = repo['.']
    work = [(1, ctx.sub(subpath)) for subpath in sorted(ctx.substate)]

    while work:
        (depth, sub) = work.pop(0)

        if hasattr(subrepo, 'relpath'):
            relpath = subrepo.relpath(sub)
        else:
            relpath = subrepo.subrelpath(sub)

        rev=sub._repo[sub._state[1]].rev()

        ui.debug(str(rev) + " " + str(sub._repo[sub._state[1]].user()) + " " + str(sub._repo[sub._state[1]].date()) + "\n")

        if depth>1:
            raise Exception("No support for nested levels deeper than 1 yet.")

    runcmd(ui, repo.root, files, str(depth) + relpath, rev, relpath, changesets, allchangesets)

        if isinstance(sub, subrepo.hgsubrepo):
            rev = sub._state[1]
            ctx = sub._repo[rev]
            w = [(depth + 1, ctx.sub(subpath)) 
                 for subpath in sorted(ctx.substate)]
            work.extend(w)

def runcmd(ui, root, files, name, revision, path, changesets, allchangesets):
    files.append(root + "/" + name + ".hg")
    if (revision<=changesets) or allchangesets:
       cmd="hg bundle -a " + root + "/" + name + ".hg"
    else:
       cmd="hg bundle --base " + str(revision-changesets)+ " "  + root + "/" + name + ".hg"
    ui.note(_("Working on '%s' in %s\n") % (path, root))
    ui.debug( "command line: "+ cmd +"\n")
    util.system(cmd, 
        cwd=os.path.join(root, path),
        onerr=util.Abort,
        errprefix=_('terminated bundlesub in %s') % path)


cmdtable = {
    "bundlesb":
        (bundlesb,
         [('c', 'changesets', 10, _('the number of recent changesets to include in the bundle'), 'N'),
          ('a', 'all', None, _('include all changesets in the bundle')),],
         _('[-c|-a] FILE...'))

}
```

And the other way around:

```
 """execute the UnBundle command in a repository and each subrepository
           for a file created with BundleSb"""

# unbundlesub.py - execute the UnBundle command in a repository and each subrepository
#
# Copyright 2012 Johan G.
#
# This software may be used and distributed according to the terms of
# the GNU General Public License version 2 or any later version.

import os
import zipfile
#import glob
from mercurial.i18n import _
from mercurial import extensions, subrepo, util

def unbundlesb(ui, repo, *args, **opts):
    """execute the UnBundle command in a repository and each subrepository
        for a file created with BundleSb

    Updates the current repository from a combined bundle (with hgs extention). 

    Use --verbose/-v to print more detailed information during the operation. 
    """
    ui.status("Starting unbundle operation\n")

    update = opts.get('update')
    file = os.path.splitext(' '.join(args))[0] + '.hgs'
    if (file==''):
       raise ValueError("FILE cannot be empty")

    ui.debug("input filename=" + file + "\n")
    zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(file, "r" )
    for info in zfile.infolist():
        ui.debug(info.filename + " " + str(info.date_time) + " " + str(info.file_size) + " " + str(info.compress_size) +"\n")
    zfile.extract(info,repo.root)
        runcmd(ui, repo.root, info.filename, update)
        #delete all the compressed .hg files
    os.remove(os.path.join(repo.root, info.filename)) 

    zfile.close()

    ui.status("\nOperation complete\n")


def runcmd(ui, root, name, update):
    level=name[0]
    rep=name[1:len(name)-3]
    ui.debug(_("Detected level=%s for repository %s \n") % (level, rep))
    cmd="hg unbundle "
    if (update): cmd= cmd + "-u "
    cmd= cmd + root + "\\" + name 
    ui.note(_("Working on '%s' in %s\n") % (rep, root))
    if (level == '1'):
        wd=os.path.join(root, rep)
    elif (level=='0'):
        wd=root
    else:
       raise Exception("Do not know what to do with a level >1")

    ui.debug(_("command line: %s in working directory %s\n") % (cmd, wd))

    util.system(cmd, 
            cwd=wd,
            onerr=util.Abort,
            errprefix=_('terminated unbundlesub in %s') % rep)


cmdtable = {
    "unbundlesb":
        (unbundlesb,
         [('u', 'update', None,
           _('update to new branch head if changesets were unbundled'))],
         _('[-u] FILE...'))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support for this, as you've noticed.

Maybe you can use the [onsub extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/OnsubExtension) I wrote. That makes it a little easier to generate patches for the subrepos:

```
$ hg onsub 'hg export -r tip -o $HG_REPO/sub-$HG_SUBPATH.diff'
```

The `HG_SUBPATH` variable is replaced with the path to the subrepo.

That fails if you have nested subrepos since `hg export` cannot write a patch names `sub-foo/bar/baz.diff`. So you need to massage the path and replace `/` with `-` or similar. You should be able to import the patches with a similar `hg onsub` call.

If you get it working, then feel free to add a note about it on the wiki page. You're also welcome to see if you can extend the onsub extension to make this easier, perhaps by adding an option to make onsub run on the top-level repo too, and a new variable that can be used directly instead of munging `HG_SUBPATH`.

Comment: Since we have nested subrepos, and i am not very familiar with Python, i think i will have to look in some other solutions first. Also, i must find a way to do this from the TortoiseHg worbench, as not all team members are familiar with the command window (we are working on windows)

Answer (score 0):

- hg archive knows about subrepo: you can export changes from single changeset (and they walk recursively, if subrepos affected in commit)
- hg diff also knows about subrepos
- in case of `hg commit --subrepos` this [commit must include all affected files](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/#committing) from subrepos also, thus - export will export (?) these files also

Comment: Yes, the archive command knows about subrepos, but it is not an easy way to work with the files, it is just a snapshot of the working directory. The export command does not know about subrepos, because in my tests the patch file contains only the difference of the .hgsubstate file. Importing this patch gives 'unknown revision' errors for the subrepos.

Comment: hg archive **can** export only files, affected by specified changeset - checkbox in THG, -I in command line (filelist can be collected by hg log --template)

Comment: Yes, but then we have to commit those files in the other repo too. this will propably give some problems the times we are able to meet and then try to sync our repo's